# "Does my thinking correct?" and "Let we go?"

Tags: grammaticality, questions

Is it grammatically correct to say
"Does my thinking correct?" and "Let we go?"?

I am half convinced that "Let we go?" is correct, and if it is, what is the difference between it and "Let us go?"?

Comment: Neither of them are correct... but it'd difficult to correct them with the little context you give.  Could you please explain why you think they are correct and how you intend to use them?

Comment: @Catija, I came across "Does my thinking correct" in one of the questions in math stackexchange, [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390274/a-problem-on-nonconstant-holomorphic-function-has-a-zero-or-no-in-the-closed-uni)
And my mom once used "Let we go?", in the context that they wanted to tell me they are going. At first I found it incorrect, but my dad said it is right.

Comment: It should be "*Is my thinking correct?*"

Comment: @Catija, even I thought so, but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Your dad was wrong. If they were leaving, they should have said "We are going"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does my thinking correct?

*Does* requires something else...

You could say:

> Does my thinking *seem/sound/look* correct?

But even this is a bit off... I'd probably say something more like:

> Does this look correct?

or just get to the point:

> Is this correct?

---

> Let we go.

*We* is a subject. *Us* is an object.

This sentence is actually:

> [You,] let us go [away from here].
>
> [Everyone,] let us go [together].

If you want to use *we*, make it the subject:

> We are going.

Comment: *Do* can be used to emphasize a verb, and is used to signal questions, *except* when the verb is *be*.  So you can say: "Do I think correctly?" but not "Do I am thinking correctly?" or "Does my thinking be correct?"-  it's just "Am I thinking correctly?" or "Is my thinking correct?"

Comment: @ultrasawblade I would argue that, as am AmE speaker, "Do I think correctly?" seems very unwieldy and unnatural.  I would personally never use it that way.

Comment: That is true - "Do I think correctly" is unwieldy - come to think of it, it sounds like you are asking permission to think.  So don't use that (even though it's grammatically correct). But yeah, "Is my thinking correct?" or "Am I thinking correctly" is much better and should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Not all sources are genuine when it comes to the Internet, especially forums where anyone can type anything. There are no editors keeping their eyes on the content posted.

> Does my thinking correct? -is completely *incorrect!*

Wherever you have read, don't believe it.

So is with `let we go` -don't trust this. Say, `let's go` i.e. `let us go.` There is no difference because `let we go` does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

As Catija says, the second sentence should be "Let us go." "We" is used for a subject, "us" for an object. The subject of an imperative sentence like this is the implied "you". It is not "we" who are letting someone go, it is "you". "We" are being allowed to go. Thus, "we" is the object, and should be "us".

"Does my thinking correct?" should be "Is my thinking correct?" Maybe it's simpler to understand this if we recast the sentence from a question to a statement. The corresponding statement would be, "My thinking does/is correct." "Correct" here is being used as an adjective: we are describing "my thinking". An adjective, i.e. a description, does not "do" anything. It just is or it isn't. So you would say "My thinking IS correct".

If you were describing an action performed by your thinking, then you would use "does". Like, "My thinking does help you", (or more simply, "My thinking helps you", but that's not the point here), or as a question, "Does my thinking help you".